# Maven wagon error when trying to copy artifact

Tags: java, maven, wagon, maven-wagon-plugin

I am trying to use the Maven Wagon plugin to copy artifacts to a server.

I have set it up as follows:

```
<build>
<extensions>
    <extension>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
       <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
       <version>${maven.wagon.version}</version>
 </extension>
</extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
               <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${maven.wagon.version}</version>
              <!--  <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.wagon.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
               </dependencies> -->
               <configuration>
                    <serverId>appui</serverId>
                    <fromFile>${project.build.directory}</fromFile>
                    <includes>${project.build.finalName}.war</includes>
                    <url>scp://localhost:2221/</url>                     
                    <toDir>/opt/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments</toDir>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                 <execution>

                   <id>upload-war-to-server</id>
                   <phase>upload</phase>
                   <goals>
                     <goal>upload-single</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                        <serverId>appui</serverId>
                        <fromFile>${project.build.directory}</fromFile>
                        <includes>${project.build.finalName}.war</includes>
                        <url>scp://localhost:2221/opt/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments</url>            

                    </configuration>
                 </execution>
               </executions>
        </plugin>
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:1.0:upload-single (default-cli) on project app.ui: The parameters 'fromFile', 'url' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:1.0:upload-single are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:1.0:upload-single (default-cli) on project app.ui: The parameters 'fromFile', 'url' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:1.0:upload-single are missing or invalid
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:221)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterException: The parameters 'fromFile', 'url' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:1.0:upload-single are missing or invalid
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:576)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:529)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParameterException
```

I have searched github to see how others use Maven Wagon, and I cannot see anything wrong with how I am using it.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration of the [`wagon-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/upload-single-mojo.html) is incorrect: `<fromFile>` need to be a reference to a *file* and not a directory. Also, there is no `<includes>` tag, as per the documentation.

If you reference the generated Maven artifact (`${project.build.finalName}.war`), you need to make sure the `upload-single` goal is executed after `package` phase (`deploy`, for example, would be appropriate). In your configuration, you have bound the `upload-single` goal to phase "upload", which does not exist.

This would be the final configuration :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.wagon.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>upload-war-to-server</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>upload-single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <serverId>appui</serverId>
                <fromFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</fromFile>
                <url>scp://localhost:2221/opt/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments</url>            
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```